Symfony API Platform relation more than one
I'm new in Symfony 6 and I have to create a database structure using api platform
I want to create a table named Place and that place has photos like oneToMany relationship also each place has a address and location and belong to a sellerUser oneToOne but can be null
The selleruser extends by User and there are two type users as SellerUser and CustomeUser
Also each user has a photo, address, location, (string) name, surname, email, password
And I want to use uuid generated by constructor and the owners has a primary key and property objects has a foreign key. I couldn't implement it.
these are my entities:
User.php :
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $surname = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 50)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?\DateTimeImmutable $registrationDate = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'owner', targetEntity: Photo::class)]
    private Collection $photos;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'owner', targetEntity: Address::class)]
    private Collection $address;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->address = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getSurname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function setSurname(string $surname): static
    {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): static
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): static
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRegistrationDate(): ?\DateTimeImmutable
    {
        return $this->registrationDate;
    }

    public function setRegistrationDate(\DateTimeImmutable $registrationDate): static
    {
        $this->registrationDate = $registrationDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Photo>
     */
    public function getPhotos(): Collection
    {
        return $this->photos;
    }

    public function addPhoto(Photo $photo): static
    {
        if (!$this->photos->contains($photo)) {
            $this->photos->add($photo);
            $photo->setOwner($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePhoto(Photo $photo): static
    {
        if ($this->photos->removeElement($photo)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($photo->getOwner() === $this) {
                $photo->setOwner(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Address>
     */
    public function getAddress(): Collection
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function addAddress(Address $address): static
    {
        if (!$this->address->contains($address)) {
            $this->address->add($address);
            $address->setOwner($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeAddress(Address $address): static
    {
        if ($this->address->removeElement($address)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($address->getOwner() === $this) {
                $address->setOwner(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}


CustomerUser.php:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\CustomerUserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CustomerUserRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class CustomerUser extends User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}


SellerUser.php:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\SellerUserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: SellerUserRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class SellerUser extends User
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private ?Place $place = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getPlace(): ?Place
    {
        return $this->place;
    }

    public function setPlace(?Place $place): static
    {
        $this->place = $place;

        return $this;
    }
}


Place.php:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\PlaceRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PlaceRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class Place
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $name = null;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'place', targetEntity: Photo::class)]
    private Collection $photos;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private ?Address $address = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(inversedBy: 'place', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?Location $location = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->photos = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): static
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Photo>
     */
    public function getPhotos(): Collection
    {
        return $this->photos;
    }

    public function addPhoto(Photo $photo): static
    {
        if (!$this->photos->contains($photo)) {
            $this->photos->add($photo);
            $photo->setPlace($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removePhoto(Photo $photo): static
    {
        if ($this->photos->removeElement($photo)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($photo->getPlace() === $this) {
                $photo->setPlace(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getAddress(): ?Address
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress(?Address $address): static
    {
        $this->address = $address;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLocation(): ?Location
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    public function setLocation(Location $location): static
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }
}


Photo.php:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\PhotoRepository;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: PhotoRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class Photo
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::TEXT)]
    private ?string $uri = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'photos')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    private ?User $owner = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'photos')]
    private ?Place $place = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUri(): ?string
    {
        return $this->uri;
    }

    public function setUri(string $uri): static
    {
        $this->uri = $uri;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOwner(): ?User
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    public function setOwner(?User $owner): static
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlace(): ?Place
    {
        return $this->place;
    }

    public function setPlace(?Place $place): static
    {
        $this->place = $place;

        return $this;
    }
}



Location.php:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\LocationRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: LocationRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class Location
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $latitude = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $longitude = null;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'location', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private ?Place $place = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLatitude(): ?int
    {
        return $this->latitude;
    }

    public function setLatitude(int $latitude): static
    {
        $this->latitude = $latitude;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLongitude(): ?int
    {
        return $this->longitude;
    }

    public function setLongitude(int $longitude): static
    {
        $this->longitude = $longitude;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPlace(): ?Place
    {
        return $this->place;
    }

    public function setPlace(Place $place): static
    {
        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($place->getLocation() !== $this) {
            $place->setLocation($this);
        }

        $this->place = $place;

        return $this;
    }
}


Address.php:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use App\Repository\AddressRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AddressRepository::class)]
#[ApiResource]
class Address
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100)]
    private ?string $country = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $city = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 100, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $district = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 20, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $postCode = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'address')]
    private ?User $owner = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(string $country): static
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCity(): ?string
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    public function setCity(?string $city): static
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDistrict(): ?string
    {
        return $this->district;
    }

    public function setDistrict(?string $district): static
    {
        $this->district = $district;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPostCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->postCode;
    }

    public function setPostCode(?string $postCode): static
    {
        $this->postCode = $postCode;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getOwner(): ?User
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }

    public function setOwner(?User $owner): static
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;

        return $this;
    }
}


I want to generate uuid using Ramsey\Uuid->uuid4() and make these relations by foreign key uuid, also I don't want to create table named user because I just want to use oop methods to not implement same things in seller and customer users
But when I migrate it the database generate user table, also the Photo and Address entities have two different fields for both place and user named owner and place but I want to just one variable named owner for two entity
